# Blog post issue in comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html but I have an issue.

As you can see in image, below comments section some irrelevant information is presenting, what is it and how to avoid it from displaying.
It will be helpful if some expert just sort it out. 
I am new to rails........

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `=` in your view in front of the `comments.each`. I should look like:

```
<% @comment.each do |comment| %>      <-- no `=` here
```